# How to generate a exe program through programming?

Tags: c#, java, c++

I want to write a application which can use to generate .exe program automatically from some word and txt files. 
How can I implement this ? Is it possible to generate a exe program with programming ?

Comment: Do you mean a compiler?

Comment: no , want to generate a .exe program which embed some information in it, and user can open and read it.

Comment: you want to compile a word document into an EXE so that a user can open the EXE and it displays the word document?

Comment: @TerrorAustralis, mate, you are too funny. :)

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote it just for having the phrase 'Is it possible to generate a program with programming?' in it...

Comment: haha, any grammar mistakes in my sentence ? Pointing out directly is appreciated ^_^

Comment: Don't worry MemoryLeak. I knew what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CodeDOM namespace to create a .NET Framework EXE. [Generating Source Code and Compiling a Program from a CodeDOM Graph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06.aspx)